# How to change field names in associative arrays returned by PDO (SELECT / WHERE) fetch queries?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When making a PDO query using fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC), it returns an associative array that I can json_encode as a string like this:

```
[{"Email_Address":"address@mail.com","Related_Data":"1239873652"}]
```

However, I would rather get the same string simplified as follows:

```
[{"from":"address@mail.com","data":"1239873652"}]
```

Not only it decreases the amount of data transmitted when the amount of records is high, but it provides an extra level of security by not exposing the names of the fields in the database.

Thanks

This is the PHP code used:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Email_Address = \'address@mail.com\'');
$array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($array);
```

When using "AS" aliases as follows:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT Email_Address AS from, Related_Data AS data FROM Messages WHERE Email_Address = \'address@mail.com\'');
```

The server returns the following error:

Warning: PDO::query(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, Related_Data AS data FROM Table WHERE Email_Address = 'address@mail.com''

Comment: You can't change the column names *while* retrieving the data; you either have to change the fields in the database ahead of time, or update the information *after* it's retrieved. And the latter would result in just as much data being transmitted.

Comment: This part is not a valid SQL statement. `Email_Address = address@mail.com`. If you would like to put a constant string value then you need to wrap it in quotes, if it is dynamic value coming from PHP use prepared statements with parameters.

Comment: _"Apparently you can use "AS" aliases, but they don't work when the SQL statement contains a "WHERE" portion."_ They certainly do. Show us your broken attempt using `AS` (including the error message, not just "it doesn't work") so we can help you fix it.

Comment: SOLVED. The problem was the usage of the alias "from" which is reserved and cannot be used. Thank you both for asking to expand and better explain the case. It helped me find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could and you should list all your columns in SELECT statement. You can then try aliasing them:

```
SELECT 
    Email_Address AS mail, 
    Related_Data AS data 
FROM Table
WHERE Email_Address = ?
```

Comment: Thank you Dharman. I tried that option but it did not work. It seems that the "AS" statement is meant to be used when you link other tables.

Comment: @andres Could you take a look at this article, please? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

Comment: Thanks again Dharman. My problem was the WHERE statement. I removed it from the sample code in order to simplify it. Is there a way to use aliases in SELECT / WHERE statements?

Comment: @Andres Expand on what you mean by "it did not work". What did you see? Was there an error? What happened? We cannot help you if all you say is "it did not work". Take the extra twenty seconds to help us help you!!

Comment: SOLVED. The problem was the usage of the alias "from" which is reserved and cannot be used. Thank you both for asking to expand and better explain the case. It helped me find the solution.

Comment: @Andres I am glad it helped you. If you would like to let others know that my answer was helpful you can accept it.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Check.